# Moq Generate test for Generic Repository

Tags: c#, moq

How can the following method that utilizes a Generic Repository, be mocked using MOQ?

```
public Employee GetEmployeeByUserName(Employee employee)
{
   return _employeeRepository.Find().FirstOrDefault(i => i.User_Name == 
          employee.User_Name);
}
```

Im' stuck settting up moq using this:

```
mockEmployeeRep.Setup(rep=>rep.Find()......<------What goes here?
```

This utilizes the following repository:

```
public class EmployeeRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class        
{           
        ... 
        public IQueryable<T> Find()    
        {    
            var table = this.LookupTableFor(typeof(T));    
            return table.Cast<T>();    
        }   
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to moq an `IQueryable` is to use a `List<T>` and use the `AsQueryable` method.

```
var employees = new List<Employee>();

employees.Add(...);

var mockEmployeeRepository = new Mock<IRepository<Employee>>();

mockEmployeeRepository.Setup(x => x.Find()).Returns(employees.AsQueryable());

// continue with the rest of your test setup
```